# Sorting by value

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    If Target.Column = 1 Then

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("A5:J33" & lastRow).Sort key1:=Range("A5:A33" & lastRow), order1:=x1Ascending, Header:=xlNo

    End If

End Sub
```

The Range I am trying to sort is  A5:J33 and How I want it sorted is by the data in A5:A33 after it is enter

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the lastRow in column A `lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` , but you are not implementing the result correctly:

`Range("A5:J33" & lastRow)` and `Range("A5:A33" & lastRow)` should be `Range("A5:J" & lastRow)` and `Range("A5:A" & lastRow)`.

Try the modified code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    If Target.Column = 1 Then

        Dim lastRow As Long

        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:A" & lastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With ActiveSheet.Sort
            .SetRange Range("A1:J" & lastRow)
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code but for some reason it's still not working, I feel like I am doing something wrong :(

Comment: @littlejiver what do you mean by not working ? are you getting a run-time error ? or you are not getting the desired result ?

Comment: literally nothing happens I am wondering now if I have excel setup right to run the script